# Automatically change cell value based on the current date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Basically, I'm having a table where A1 shows the status (active / inactive). C1 has a date and when that date comes (lets say it's tomorrow), the value of A1 should change from *active* to *inactive*. Can someone please help out with this one. I tried playing around with =INDEX formula but can't get it to work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this formula:

=IF(C1>TODAY(),"Inactive","Active")

Answer (score 0):

Use an if() statement like so:

```
=if(C1<now(),"Active","Inactive")
```

You may need to check the formatting of C1 or the cell with the date.